# I want to exit the reccursion when i input just a newline in erlang

Tags: erlang

```
-module(solution).  
-export([main/0]).  
 do_it(_X,0)->  
    true;  
 do_it(X,K) when K>0->   
     io:format("~p~n",[X]),  
     do_it(X,K-1).  
kis(T)->  
    {ok,[K]}=io:fread("","~d"),    
    do_it(K,T),  
    kis(T).  
main()->  
    {ok,[K]}=io:fread("","~d"),  
    kis(K).
```

#### Input (stdin)

2
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

#### MY Output (stdout)

1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
6
6
7
7
8
8
9
9
10
10

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,eof},[{solution,kis,1,[{file,"/run-yvsveha40GAvIJDSfd6N/solution.erl"},{line,9}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}
```

#### Expected Output

1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
6
6
7
7
8
8
9
9
10
10

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
kis(T) ->
    case io:fread("","~d") of        
        {ok,[K]} -> do_it(K,T), kis(T);
        _        -> ok
    end.

main()->
    case io:fread("","~d") of
        {ok,[K]} -> kis(K);
        _        -> ok
end.
```